# wifi network list and taskbar wifi icon is missing after windows10 update

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-update, updates

after windows10 KB4486561 update my wifi icon and wifi list disappeared. My wifi is working very well though. I tried all suggested solution here:

https://www.intowindows.com/fix-wireless-icon-missing-from-taskbar-in-windows-10/

and here

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/windows-could-not-start-error-1068-the-dependency/7963d72a-5d73-44fe-8316-058c46235737

but none of them worked for me. Also I tried to start "network list" service but it popped up error message and it didn't work either. How can I solve this problem?

[here is my icon list from settings :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezYfk.png)

[..and here is my taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j07a.png)

Answer (score 0):

By any chance do you have Office 2003 installed? It will cause this issue and others like it.

Comment: Could you give a bit more information? It seems odd at first glance that Office 03 merely being installed would hide the wifi UI.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that Office 2003 would do that either but it does. Not only does it remove the wireless icons but it removes option from the start menu power button. It is not compatible with Windows 10. You need to go in to add/remove programs and uninstall it. The icons and buttons will come back after a reboot. I would assume from your response that iy is installed?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after a more recent update, and the problem was ultimately caused by system services being disabled because I had selective startup enabled.

The remedy was to hit Win + R, type msconfig, select Normal startup, and reboot.

You may then be able to re-disable the startup items you want off, checking to make sure none of your selections bring the issue back.